# How to uninstall the installed extension without Magento Connect?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, third-party-module, uninstall

I installed extension by unzipping the .zip file in root folder. Now I would like to Uninstall it completely and reinstall the different version (much never version), there are huge differences in 2016 version and many more files to it than original 2013 version.

What is the proper way to uninstall extension that was installed without Magento Connect Manager?

Answer (score 1):

There is simple step to do that but i that process maybe you lose some data of that extension.

**First**

Try to upgrade it by pasting the new version through zip the extension will be update automatically.

> *Note:: clear you cache after that*

**Second**

You want to remove the extension and install new one. go your **core_resource** table and delete the module entry from their. Paste new version and clear you cache.

> *Note:: In this process you may loss the old data of extension*

Comment: Any way to actually remove the extension without going folder to folder manual deletion ?

Comment: @Icon as i mention past in main folder all file will be replaced you don't have to delete it upgrade the extension.

Comment: Appreciate the response! But I am also wondering what if I want to Completely delete the extension. How do I do it?

Comment: it is better to disabled the extension from backend `system->configuration > advanced > disbaled module out`  or manually from `app > etc > modules > Namespace_Modulename.xml` make true to `false` for complate you must known to every file that module have see the structure of zip and munally delete all files. and remove the entry from `core_resource` table

Comment: @Icon there is not simple way delete the extension..

Answer (score 0):

1. By navigating in the Magento backend to **System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable modules output** you can easily disable certain modules.

Or

2. Goto root folder and open this path. `app-->etc-->modules` and find `Namespace_Module.xml` file and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`